# Cheching if time passed or not

Tags: python-3.x

I have files with names like "30.06.2017_10.30.txt". In these files are the details of a date and the name is time of it. I want my program to check if this date is active, I also want to check if the date in the name of file has passed or not. I tried the following:

```
        i = "30.06.2017_10.30.txt"
        print(int(i[6:10]))  #1
        if int(i[6:10]) < int(time.strftime("%Y", time.gmtime())):
            print(i[6:10])   #2
            pass
        else:
            if int(i[3:4]) < int(time.strftime("%m", time.gmtime())):
                print(i[3:4])
                pass
            else:
                if int(i[0:1]) < int(time.strftime("%d", time.gmtime())):
                    print(i[0:1])
                    pass                        
                else:
                    if int(i[11:12]) < int(time.strftime("%H", time.gmtime())):
                        print(i[11:12])
                        pass
                    else:
                        if int(i[14:15]) < int(time.strftime("%M", time.gmtime())):
                            print(i[14:15])
                            pass
                        else:
                            print("date is active")
```

Problem is: #1 prints "2017" but #2 prints "0". So it passes and date is seen as not active. Did I code that wrong?

Comment: Side-point: all your `pass`es are redundant.

Comment: @MrGrj There were no printings before. They are for diagnose. Added later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [i:j], it excludes the last index. It means take from ith character upto (j-1)th character.

i[6:10] -  this means from 6th character upto 9th character (total 4 chars, "2017" in your case"

i[3:5] - this will give you 2 characters -3rd and 4th- ("06"), what you really want.

Comment: The answer of @MrGrj made me think that to and tried. So this bug is solved. Heading to another bug XD. Thanks to everyone :)